# how to refresh the data being loaded on the form after showing it off?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a a div, wherein, it displays the data, and beside it, is an edit button..if one clicks the edit button, it hides the div and shows a different div with input forms which allows the user to update the data..the problem now is, when the user submits the form, my script updates the data and hides this input forms and shows again the former div of data display, the data shown is not updated....my question now is,, how to show the updated data after the script show() it again ?

here's my jquery ajax code

```
$(function(){
   $('#profileinfoedit').click(function(){
       $('#profileinfomain').hide();
       $('#profileinfoajax').show();

   $('form#pdetails').submit(function(){
      var cvid = $('#cvid').val();
      var resumetitle = $('#resumetitle').val();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var dob = $('#dob').val();
      var gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'classes/ajax.personalupdate.php',
          data: $("form#pdetails").serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#profileinfoajax').hide();
            $('#profileinfomain').show();
          }

      });
      return false;
   });

   });
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So location.reload is just refreshing the page, which as you have discovered is a quick and dirty fix.

If you want to do it without a page refresh, you would have to regenerate the html for just the 'profileinfomain' element from data received back from ajax.personalupdate.php. I would assume you would only want to do this on "success".

One approach would be to have the success data contain the html needed to regenerate the 'profileinfomain' element html. So perhaps have php return back data.profileinfomain_html, and then:

```
$('#profileinfomain').html(data.profileinfomain_html);
```

which will replace the inner content of the profileinfomain element.

If you are working in a framework of some sort, have the profileinfomain inner html content be a partial template included in so you only have to maintain its html in one place.

Answer (score 0):

was able to sort it out via

```
    $('#profileinfomain').show('normal',function(){
       location.reload();
    });
```

but, isn't there any better way to do this?

Comment: To be able to reload parts of the page, you need to have sync between front-end and back-end code. You can code it yourself or use something like http://agiletoolkit.org/intro/javascript